# Convert .net System.Int32[] to matlab matrix

Tags: c#, matlab

I have developed C# dll as assembly that has a method which returns a generic list - `List<T>`.
I am calling this method from Matlab and get the returned values as `System.Int32[]`.

How do I convert this Type to Matlab matrix (or cells) in order to use it more freely inside Matlab?

Even better, can I make the dll to auto return 'Matlab style' array if it being called by Matlab?

Comment: To the last sentence: I doubt that it is possible for a function to return a different type based on the caller in a static language. I also would say that that's a quite confusing design. Instead, I'd make two different methods, like `getList` and `getMatlabMatrix`.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we had the following array of type `System.Int32[]` (as returned by your C# function):

```
arr = NET.createArray('System.Int32',5);
for i=1:5
    arr.Set(i-1, i);
end
```

Now to convert to a MATLAB matrix, we can simply do:

```
M = double(arr)
```

or be more specific:

```
M = int32(arr)
```

The result:

```
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class             Attributes

  M         1x5                20  int32                       
  arr       1x1                60  System.Int32[]
```

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Builder NE add-on  will hopefully solve your problem. Try it.